# Error: Timeout was reached using apt-get with Partner repo

Tags: apt, 22.04, timeout

Could someone help / share their knowledge on how to solve the error on timeout which I see comes up mostly after every apt-get operation.

Eg 1:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InReleaseHit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Error: Timeout was reached
Reading package lists... Done
```

Eg 2:

```
sudo apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  docbook-xml libglu1-mesa libopengl0 libpipeline1 libyelp0 sgml-base
  sgml-data x11-session-utils xbitmaps xinit xml-core yelp-xsl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 12 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
After this operation, 6,795 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 211270 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing docbook-xml (4.5-11) ...
Removing libglu1-mesa:amd64 (9.0.2-1) ...
Removing libopengl0:amd64 (1.4.0-1) ...
Removing libpipeline1:amd64 (1.5.5-1) ...
Removing libyelp0:amd64 (42.1-1) ...
Removing sgml-data (2.0.11+nmu1) ...
Removing xml-core (0.18+nmu1) ...
Removing sgml-base (1.30) ...
Removing x11-session-utils (7.7+4build2) ...
Removing xbitmaps (1.1.1-2.1ubuntu1) ...
Removing xinit (1.4.1-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing yelp-xsl (42.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Error: Timeout was reached
```

My sources.list has:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the Partner archive from `sources.list`, [since this is deprecated](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/01/ubuntu-is-axing-the-partner-repo-nobody-uses/amp).

So comment out that line:

```
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
```

Then it should work for you.